# Clarity datagrid how to replace a row when using ngProjectAs?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

In order to replace a row when it is expanded the documentations looks like this:

```
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let user of users">
    <-- Cells declarations -->
    <clr-dg-cell>...</clr-dg-cell>

    <clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded [clrDgReplace]="true">
        Lorem ipsum...
    </clr-dg-row-detail>
</clr-dg-row>
```

This works but I also want to replace `<clr-dg-row-detail>` with my own component so I can lazy load the details.  The documentation for that looks like this:

```
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let user of users">
    <-- Cells declarations -->
    <clr-dg-cell>...</clr-dg-cell>

    <my-detail *clrIfExpanded [user]="user" ngProjectAs="clr-dg-row-detail"></my-detail>
</clr-dg-row>
```

I tried placing `[clrDgReplace]="true"` on my custom component and inside of ngProjectAs but it throws errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[clrDgReplace]="true"` needs to be on the `<clr-dg-row-detail>` element itself, it's an input of the row detail component.
So in your case, the `<clr-dg-row-detail [clrDgReplace]="true">` is inside the template of your custom component.

Comment: Works perfectly!